# Solving a system of ODE's via explicit Euler method (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, ode

The title speaks for itself. I implement an algorithm that works perfectly on paper but it ain't on Matlab. It doesn't really matter if you are familiar with the method because my problem is rather coding than setting up an algorithm.

```
function [t, r] = SystemOfEquations_Euler_Explicit(f, interval, r0, h)

% f is a set of functions like : f = @ (x1,...,xn)[f1,...fn]

% interval specifies the range that i want to solve ODE's 

% r0 is the initial value's of f1,..fn

% h is step size 



N = length(r0)

t = interval(1):h:interval(2)

n = length(t)

r = zeros(n, N)

r(1,:) = r0

for i = 1:n-1

% Here is the problem , it cain't evaluate the function at r(i,:)
r(i+1, :) = r(i, :)+h*f(t(i),r(i,:)) 

end



end
```

As i mentioned in the comment, i need to evaluate a set of n data points in every function out of f , so i have the first argument it is always a number nl. **t(i)** but the n-1 arguments are already initialised in rows of matrix r, how can i access those inside f ?

Comment: What values are you using for `f`, `interval`,`r0`, and `h` ? Are you receiving any error message?

Comment: @SardarUsama the f is an array of multivariable functions , interval is [a,b] just two numbers and r0 is the initial values corresponding to f's and h is arbitrary choose 0.1 or whatever

Comment: for instance :  `f = @(x,y,z)[(-y+z)*exp(1-x)+0.5*y,y-z^2];`
 `SystemOfEquations_Euler_Explicit(f, [0,3], [3, 0.2], 0.25)`

Comment: @SamFarjamirad if that is the function, then your call is wrong. You call it with 2 inputs instead of 3, and the first input is a scalar, but the second input is a long array.  How do you want to convert that to `(x,y,z)`???

Comment: For the given `f` you need to use: `r(i+1, :) = r(i, :)+h*f(t(i),r(i,1), r(i,2))` Reason is what @Ander said

Comment: @AnderBiguri Actually that's my question , how ?

Comment: @SamFarjamirad How what? just give the `x,y,z` values. your problem is that you dont even have those values, its a bit confusing. You give your initial conditions as 2 values and a function of 3 inputs. Sardar suggestion shoudl work a priory, but this code is a bit confusing in structure

Comment: @AnderBiguri I mean how to evaluate the content of an array inside f ? in this case i have n clue how many variables does every f has it could be 2 or whatever

Comment: @SardarUsama It works if your function has three variable but how can i get that work for an arbitrary function with unknown numbers of variable ?

Comment: `input=[t(i) ,r(i,:) ]; f(input);` works?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Nope it interprets it as single input !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example

```
f = @(x,y,z)[(-y+z)*exp(1-x)+0.5*y,y-z^2];
SystemOfEquations_Euler_Explicit(f, [0,3], [3, 0.2], 0.25);
```

the given function `f` has 3 arguments while the solver expects a function that takes 2 arguments. The easiest and natural way to repair this is to adapt the definition of `f` to

```
f = @(t,y)[(-y(2)+y(3))*exp(1-y(1))+0.5*y(2),y(2)-y(3)^2];
```

or make it a complete function

```
function prime = f(t,u)
    x=u(1); y=u(2); z=u(3);
    prime = [(-y+z)*exp(1-x)+0.5*y,y-z^2];
end;
```

You could also just change the call of the solver without changing `f`, this would then look like

```
SystemOfEquations_Euler_Explicit(@(t,u)f(u(1),u(2),u(3)), [0,3], [3, 0.2], 0.25);
```

Comment: Thanks! But is there any way to generalise the function with unknown numbers of variables ?

Comment: Which function? The solver gets the state space dimension from the initial vector, the ODE function is specific to the problem. In general use the form `f(t,u)` with a state space vector `u` as the solver expects, this is also the format the whole mathematical theory behind this, analytical as well as numerical, uses. Of course, the state space dimension should be consistent over all inputs, ODE function and initial vector.